# image update successfully, but when i click edit button and without select image i m submit image is display black on table

Tags: php, oop

```
<?php

session_start();

require "database.php";

$db = new database();

$operation = $_REQUEST['action'];

     $file = uniqid() . " - " . $_FILES['document']['name'];

     $result = move_uploaded_file(
          $_FILES['document']['tmp_name'],
           "uploads/" . $file );

   switch ($operation) 
   {
    case 'Add':
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $image = "uploads/" . $file;
        $result = $db->insert($name,$image);
        break;

    case 'update':
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $image = "uploads/" . $file;
        $result = $db->update($id,$name,$image);
        break;

    case 'delete':
        $result = $db->delete($_REQUEST['id']);
        break;      

    default:
        echo "invalid request";
        break;
   }

   header("Location:display.php");

?>
```

Comment: Please update your question and explain what issue you are facing, your current vs. expected result etc.

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul   name and image update successfully, but when i am only name edit and not edit image then image blanck on table...

Comment: public function update($id,$name,$image)
    {
       
     $query = "UPDATE `customers` SET name='$name',
         image ='$image' WHERE id=$id";

     return mysqli_query($this->connect,$query);
    }

Comment: @AbhishekPansuriya I've given an answer below. Hopefully that will resolve your issue.

Comment: @Rajdeep Paul, tahnk u , my query is solved

Comment: @AbhishekPansuriya You have been given two answers below, accept one of the answers to close the question. And if you have solved on your own then write an answer an accept it, otherwise this question will be floating around as *open* question. [How to accept answer on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) function to check whether a file is uploaded with the form or not. So accordingly, change your code in the following way,

```
...
$operation = $_REQUEST['action'];
$file = null;
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['document']['tmp_name'])){
    $file = uniqid() . " - " . $_FILES['document']['name'];
    $result = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['document']['tmp_name'], "uploads/" . $file );
}

switch($operation){
    case 'Add':
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $image = ($file == null) ? null : "uploads/" . $file;
        $result = $db->insert($name,$image);
        break;

    case 'update':
        $id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
        $name = $_REQUEST['name'];
        $image = ($file == null) ? null : "uploads/" . $file;
        $result = $db->update($id,$name,$image);
        break;
    case 'delete':
        ...
}
...
```

And your `update` method would be like this,

```
public function update($id, $name, $image) { 
    $query = "UPDATE customers SET name='$name'";
    if($image != null){
        $query .= ", image ='$image'";
    }
    $query .=  " WHERE id=$id";
    return mysqli_query($this->connect,$query); 
}
```

---

**Sidenote:** Learn about [**prepared statement**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) because right now your query is susceptible to SQL injection attack. Also see [**how you can prevent SQL injection in PHP**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).